# Lua 5.4 Calling a function declared as a string

Tags: lua

I would need to call a function that is declared as a string

i.e `local abc = "function x() print('math.sqrt(25)') end"`

i've tried  `load(abc)` that gives me no errors but nothing is printed and `print(load(abc))` that returns `function: 0000000000ebcea0`

I've made another tries but nothing seems to suit my case (or probably i'm just bad)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read the manual...

> If there are no syntactic errors, load returns the compiled chunk as a
> function

If you want that function to be called, call it.

```
local abc = "function x() print('math.sqrt(25)') end"

local loadedFunction = load(abc)
loadedFunction()
```

or simply

```
load(abc)()
```

Of course you should check wether load actually succeeded.

If you want something to happen you probably should also call the function that has been defined by the function you loaded.

```
load(abc)()
x()
```

Comment: That's one of the other tried i made, but the result it's the same, the function seems to not be executed

Comment: @DarkSideOfTheCode I can only refer to the code in your question. loading the string will return a function that, when called will define a global function x when called will print math.sqrt(25)

Comment: The part that i missed it's that load() doesn't execute the function automatically when it's called. Thanks :)